# Why I am not getting the correct output for array.set?

Tags: android, arraylist

Firstly, I am storing the data in ArrayList.Now based on my index(current position) I want to replace that data with new data,but what I am getting is
old data,old data,old data,true,true,new data,new data....

Any suggestions

```
  ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (arr.isEmpty()) {
        for(int i = 0;i<=mcq.size();i++) {
            arr.add(s);

        }


    } else {

        arr.set(currentPosition, String.valueOf(arr.add(s)));



    }
```

"s" is a String value I am getting from somewhere else.

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve - look at the list documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html set is replacing the element, add is adding at the end and now you add something at the end end then replace the current postion with 'true', which is the result off add

Comment: probalby you mean arr.set(currentPosition,s);

Comment: Yes, I have to replace the arr.add(s)  with "s"...

Answer (score 1):

This looks really weird:

```
arr.set(currentPosition, String.valueOf(arr.add(s)));
```

`ArrayList.set` changes the elements stored at `currentPosition`. You want it to change it to the string value of what `arr.add` returns.

`ArrayList.add` returns a boolean, so there you get your `true` values from.

I think you want to do `arr.set(currentPosition, s);`

Comment: thanks ........@RvdK